# how to solve this terminal or code problem

Tags: c, fork

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(){
    
    int x;
    pid_t myPID,childPID;
    x=10;
    myPID = getpid();
    childPID=fork();

    printf("%s \n","how are you");
    
    return 0;
}
```

return ans this format.not print new line.

```
bobi@bobi-VirtualBox:~/code$ gcc parent_child.c -o parent_child

bobi@bobi-VirtualBox:~/code$ ./parent_child

how are you 

bobi@bobi-VirtualBox:~/code$ how are you
```

Comment: The code is clear. What was your expectation of what should happen? Presumably it did not match what happened.

Comment: how are you

bobi@bobi-VirtualBox:~/code$ how are you                                      this part show how are you                                                                                                                         how are you  ,this format

Comment: Please add this properly formatted to your question. In comments no formatting is available.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the child to run in the background and print over the shell after the parent returns? Try:

```
 childPID=fork();
 if (!childPID) {sleep(1);}
 printf("%s \n","how are you");
```